# Change the Image Link to "#" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, href, prop

I validate image path whether it is image path or some other path. If it is the image then replace the particular href value to `#` But the # value is affected all links. How can i replace the image link to `#`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("a").each(function(i, el) {
      var href_value = el.href;
      if (/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/.test(href_value)) {
         jQuery('a').prop('href', '#');
      }
   });
});
```

Here is the

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/Q3Zwh/2/)**

Any Suggestion would be great.

Comment: `jQuery(el).prop('href', '#');` instead of `jQuery('a').prop('href', '#');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use *this*

```
jQuery(this).prop('href', '#');
```

or

```
jQuery(el).prop('href', '#');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `this` like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $("a").each(function() {
            var href_value = $(this).attr('href');
            if (/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/.test(href_value)) {
               jQuery(this).prop('href', '#');
            } 
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason all links get their href set to # is that you use jQuery('a').prop('href', '#'); when you find an image link.
jQuery('a') finds all a-tags in the entire page.

Try using your el variable instead. Something like:

```
if (/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/.test(href_value)) {
   jQuery(el).prop('href', '#');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below code

```
el.href="#";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Zwh/3/